# Deciding ThreadPool count in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Other day, I had a requirement of concurrently accessing objects from my repository through Cache facade. For this, I decided to take use of Executor Framework from Java concurrency API.

For this, examples across the web state to initialize ExecutorService using 10 threads i.e. Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10). But when I tried to benchmark this figure in my application, I could see a better performance at 25 threads and not above that.

So, the question is that is 10 a recommended value for this implementation or I can choose a better value depending upon the load. What are the factors to keep in mind while deciding this.

Also, when to choose Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10) instead of FixedThreadPool impl.

Comment: If you see better performance consistently at 25 then use 25. Or create a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a dynamic thread count. Or just make it configurable with a default of 25 (or whatever) and let advanced users choose. As for your question about scheduled thread pool vs. fixed thread pool the [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) documentation answers that.

Comment: Thanks Jason will have a look at it !!

Comment: The number of threads is certainly a tuning parameter, and the "best" number heavily depends on the target system (how many cores it has) and the actual work that is to be performed. In general, a rule of thumb is that the number of threads should be based on the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors-- . For tasks that are not compute-intensive, a higher number may be more appropriate. One could go very far here, and even consider some "self-tuning" to find the "sweet spot" automatically, but this is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Marco13 ... you are right ... my task is not very compute intensive and is depending upon database access for huge data set if not found inside the cache facade. BTW, how can I calculate number of threads depending upon the number of processors. like the server have 8 processors and with count of >20 threads I can monitor that concurrent requests get fatigued.

Comment: Sorry, there is a really *deep* knowledge about the actual setup and task required in order to give a really "profound" answer here. A first shot could be `numThreads = Runtime.availableProcessors()*2`, but this might be wrong on a machine with 1 core or with 64 cores. Again, the "best" parameter is probably situation-dependent in many ways.